# Best way to align/indent code for a multiline JS object?

Tags: javascript, standards

Is there a 'best way' or 'standard way' to align JS objects?

Here are some different examples:

### Align keys

```
        var boundBox = {x: click.x - boundBoxDefaultSize/2,
                        y: click.y - boundBoxDefaultSize/2,
                        width: boundBoxDefaultSize,
                        height: boundBoxDefaultSize }
```

### Align colons

```
        var boundBox = {x: click.x - boundBoxDefaultSize/2,
                        y: click.y - boundBoxDefaultSize/2,
                    width: boundBoxDefaultSize,
                   height: boundBoxDefaultSize }
```

### One line

```
        var boundBox = {x: click.x - boundBoxDefaultSize/2, y: click.y - boundBoxDefaultSize/2, width: boundBoxDefaultSize, height: boundBoxDefaultSize }
```

Comment: To those voting this question down, I'm asking if there is an industry-wide standard, not simply what opinions do people have. Like camelCaseExpectedWithJavaScript vs. ruby_uses_snake_case. The styles aren't enforced, but are pretty much expected.

Comment: There's no industry standard for Javascript layout style, it's entirely personal preference.

Comment: @Barmar I don't agree with you. most of code in Github pretty much write the same. and if there is a change  from the standard probably there is aesthetic reason for that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend you this Style guide https://github.com/airbnb/javascript

So, your code should be as follows:

```
var boundBox = {
  x: click.x - boundBoxDefaultSize/2,
  y: click.y - boundBoxDefaultSize/2,
  width: boundBoxDefaultSize,
  height: boundBoxDefaultSize
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The majority of code out there aligns objects like this:

```
var boundBox = {
      x: click.x - boundBoxDefaultSize/2,
      y: click.y - boundBoxDefaultSize/2,
      width: boundBoxDefaultSize,
      height: boundBoxDefaultSize 
}
```

If it's short enough, it can be all on one line:

```
 var boundBox = {x:x, y:y}
```

I hope that helps you.

Comment: This is indeed the preferred format of many respected JS style guides. Cf. [jQuery](https://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/#object-and-array-expressions) (explicit), [AirBnB](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#objects), [Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-object-literals) (see examples).

Answer (score 1):

One line (when enough) is fine, and so is lining up keys. I've never seen lining up on colons. If you want more structure, better line up both keys and values:

```
        var boundBox = {x:      click.x - boundBoxDefaultSize/2,
                        y:      click.y - boundBoxDefaultSize/2,
                        width:  boundBoxDefaultSize,
                        height: boundBoxDefaultSize };
```

Notice that it is also customary to use linebreaks around the braces of multiline literals, to make it look less like LISP and more like a block:

```
        var boundBox = {
            x:      click.x - boundBoxDefaultSize/2,
            y:      click.y - boundBoxDefaultSize/2,
            width:  boundBoxDefaultSize,
            height: boundBoxDefaultSize
        };
```